# how to convert currency type to number with workflow

Tags: workflow, lookup-column, 2019, currency-field

I work on SharePoint 2019 and I have a list containing name(type: text) and price
(type: currency) of food columns. How can I fetch them to other custom forms?

I use lookup type in the custom form to connect List but I can't achieve price column because of currency type.

In [Lookup column not showing currency columns](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f36ad9f9-bc97-4a65-abe1-0f145b9e2d4a/lookup-column-not-showing-currency-columns?forum=sharepointgeneral), told to create a workflow to transfer the currency values to another number or text column, how can I create a workflow to convert type?

Answer (score 0):

For this requirement, you need to create a new column of number type to hold the currency value in number format, this column you can refer in your custom forms.

To copy the currency value to number column, you need to create a SPD workflow in your list, where you will have only one action step, Set Field in Current Item, in which set the currency field value to Number field value.

Make this workflow to run on item update and item add. so you need to update all the items in your list. In this way you can bring in all currency value to number.